# How can I create a larger page-size copy of a PDF document?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

I have a PDF/X4 printer ready file for an A3 poster, and have had already printed 2500 copies at a commercial digital print shop in Europe. Went very well.

Now I want to have some A0 plastic tarps (heavy duty outdoor banners) printed at an African print shop.

I could just ask the printer "please upscale in your pre-production" but I have been to that place a few times in the past (am in Europe personally right now) and I do not trust their in-house communications between order-intake and production-shop.

So I would love to prepare them a full size A0 order file. Resolution is no issue, as their Epson printer for plastic sheets only does 300 dpi and our photos are well good enough.

So is there a tool (preferably inside Adobe Acrobat) to upscale or downscale PDFs; not in file-size but in page-size? And to make the entire content "fit" the new page size of course.

I have done virtual re-printing with some free tools but I doubt that all the X4 details remain undamaged (where needed) or get properly adjusted (where needed) to the new page size A0. Thank you.